# Heroku: tables not generated when db:migrate for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm a bit stuck in migrating database in Heroku. I've deployed app and in final stage I've done this to have PostgreSQL database migration:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant/myappname$ heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
Running rake db:migrate --trace on ⬢ myappname... up, run.5129 (Free)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
   (12.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying PRIMARY KEY)
   (6.8ms)  CREATE TABLE "ar_internal_metadata" ("key" character varying PRIMARY KEY, "value" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(5132908415839787310);
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", :environment], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "production"], ["created_at", 2017-01-26 05:33:42 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-01-26 05:33:42 UTC]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.9ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(5132908415839787310)
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
    ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant/myappname$ heroku pg:psql
--> Connecting to postgresql-cylindrical-63703
psql (9.6.1)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

mydatabasename::DATABASE=> \dt
                   List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  |     Owner
--------+----------------------+-------+----------------
 public | ar_internal_metadata | table | OWNER
 public | schema_migrations    | table | OWNER
(2 rows)
```

It looks like it is not loading my Rails5 app schema.rb
**What could be wrong, why there is no tables of my app? Thank you!**

Comment: what migrations are in your app that you expect to be run?

Comment: @sevenseacat No migrations, it's empty.

Comment: well, if there are no migrations in your app, then there won't be any changes made to your database.

Comment: @sevenseacat I have schema.rb which I want to populate - something like db:setup

Comment: If you want to load your schema.rb, use `db:schema:load`, not`db:migrate`.

Comment: @sevenseacat Nice, now it works :) I read somewhere `db:schema:load` is not working in Heroku, but obviously it was not related to Rails 5. Thanks for helping!